# How do I open an asp.net core project to the public on linux?

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core

I have a websocket server application which I have configured in the launchSettings.json file to run on port 32123:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:32123",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On my linux server, if I build the project and run it using `dotnet run`, it hosts on the correct port, but that port seems to be open to connections coming from localhost.

I tried publishing it, but the published version is running on the default ports of 5000 and 5001, even if I remove the "environmentVariables" section in launchSettings.json. Also, 5000 and 5001 do not seem accessible from outside localhost.

I'm pretty new to this, but I think I have my appSettings.json and appSettings.Development.json set up correctly (their contents are identical):

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I'm not sure what else to try here. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The console output from `dotnet run`:

```
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:32123
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/admin/Clueless-game/CluelessBackend
```

The console output from running the published version:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/admin/Clueless-game/CluelessBackend/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish
```

Comment: When you start your application, it should show you a few lines like `Now listening on: http://localhost:5000`. Can you share those?

Comment: I've added them above.

Answer (score 2):

Your application is using the URLs of the form `http://localhost:5000` and `http://localhost:32123`. `localhost` means the local machine. In other words, that URL says "only listen to connections coming from the local machine on these ports...".

If you want your program to listen to connections from any machine on the network, use a URL of the type:

```
http://*:32123
```

or

```
http://*:5001
```

The `*` means "listen to connection from any machine".

---

[`launchSettings.json` is only used for development, not for deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2019):

> In the Properties folder in an ASP.NET Core project, you can find the launchSettings.json file, which contains settings that control how your web app is started on your development machine

That's why any change you make in it is used for `dotnet run` but not via `dotnet publish`.

You can use the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to set the host/port when running the published version. For example:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5001;https://*:5002" ./published-app
```